# Is there any bandwidth limits for GDrive and Dropbox

Tags: limit, google-drive-api, dropbox, bandwidth

I want to store my website images, js, css, flash files into google drive and dropbox services.

Also I want to load files from gdrive & dropbox into my website pages...

So, I have a doubt, about there bandwidth limitations.

Is there any bandwidth limitations of there services...

Comment: I remember that once I got "sorry you can't view or download this file at this time to many users have viewed or downloaded this file recently..." while using Google Drive.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the limits of a service, not strictly about writing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Dropbox, from https://www.dropbox.com/help/4204/en:

> Links are automatically banned if they generate an uncommonly large
>   amount of traffic. For Basic accounts, the total amount of traffic
>   that all of your links together can generate without getting banned is
>   20 GB per day. For Pro and Business accounts, the limit is 200 GB per
>   day.
>
> If your account hits our limit, we'll send a message to the email
>   address registered to your account. Your links will be temporarily
>   disabled, and those who try to access them will see an error page
>   instead of your files.

Note that this is for share links, not for access via the API.